# MassTransit: publisher no longer work. Why?

Tags: masstransit

In previous project following code is working.
But now I need use MultiBus:  - EventsConsumer located into current project. - Consumer for Payment is located in outter project.
Why this approach no longer work?

=================== Error:

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Publisher.Services.Abstract.IBusPublisher Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Publisher.Services.Concrete.BusPublisher': Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.IBus' while attempting to activate 'Publisher.Services.Concrete.BusPublisher'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.IBus' while attempting to activate 'Publisher.Services.Concrete.BusPublisher'.

[image: 1st error]
[image: 2nd error]

```
// =================== Startup

using System;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.MultiBus;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using CommonTypes.Options;
using Publisher.Consumers;
using Publisher.Services.Abstract;
using Publisher.Services.Concrete;

namespace Publisher
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public interface IEventsBus : IBus { }
        public interface IPaymentBus : IBus { }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Publisher", Version = "v1" });
            });

            #region MassTransit 

            services.AddSingleton<IBusPublisher, BusPublisher>();

            services.Configure<EventsBusOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("EventsBusOptions"));
            services.Configure<PaymentBusOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("PaymentBusOptions"));

            services.AddScoped<EventsConsumer>();

            // EventsConsumer located into current project
            services.AddMassTransit<IEventsBus>(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<EventsConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventsBusOptions>>().Value;

                    cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(_options.UserName);
                        h.Password(_options.Password);
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
                    {
                        ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 15;
                        ep.ConcurrentMessageLimit = _options.UseConcurrencyLimit ?? 16;

                        ep.ConfigureConsumer<EventsConsumer>(context);
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });

            // Consumer for Payment is located in outter project
            // Did I properly describe Bus for outter consumer?
            services.AddMassTransit<IPaymentBus>(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PaymentBusOptions>>().Value;

                    cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(_options.UserName);
                        h.Password(_options.Password);
                    });


                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
                    {
                        ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 15;
                        ep.ConcurrentMessageLimit = _options.UseConcurrencyLimit ?? 16;
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
            services.AddGenericRequestClient();

            #endregion
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Publisher v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}


// =================== interface 


using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Publisher.Services.Abstract
{
    public interface IBusPublisher
    {
        Task Publish<Tin>(Tin request) where Tin : class;

        Task<Tout> GetResponse<Tin, Tout>(Tin request) where Tin : class where Tout : class;
    }
}

// =================== class

using System;
using MassTransit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Publisher.Services.Abstract;
using Publisher.Contracts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Publisher.Services.Concrete
{
    public class BusPublisher : IBusPublisher
    {
        readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
        readonly IBus _bus;

        public BusPublisher(IServiceProvider provider, IBus bus)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _bus = bus;
        }

        public async Task Publish<Tin>(Tin request) where Tin : class
        {
            try
            {
                await _bus.Publish(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }


        public async Task<Tout> GetResponse<Tin, Tout>(Tin request)
            where Tin : class
            where Tout : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (var _scope = _provider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var client = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestClient<Tin>>();
                    var response = await client.GetResponse<Tout>(request);
                    return response.Message;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem. And now I can publish message to EventsConsumer.
BUT I don't see mesages in 2nd bus queue (IPaymentBus).
Maybe I made some mistake. Plz help me to publish message in both queues.

```
//// ==================================== BusPublisher 
namespace Publisher.Services.Concrete
{
    public class BusPublisher : IBusPublisher
    {
        readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
        readonly IPublishEndpoint _bus;
        

        public BusPublisher(IServiceProvider provider, IPublishEndpoint bus)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _bus = bus;
        }

        public async Task Publish<Tin>(Tin request) where Tin : class
        {
            try
            {
                await _bus.Publish(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }


        public async Task<Tout> GetResponse<Tin, Tout>(Tin request)
            where Tin : class
            where Tout : class
        {
            try
            {
                using (var _scope = _provider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var client = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestClient<Tin>>();

                    var response = await client.GetResponse<Tout>(request);

                    return response.Message;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }


    }
}

//// ==================================== Startup
namespace Publisher
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public interface IPaymentBus : IBus { }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        ....

            #region MassTransit 

            services.Configure<EventsBusOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("EventsBusOptions"));
            services.Configure<PaymentBusOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("PaymentBusOptions"));

            services.AddScoped<EventsConsumer>();
            services.AddScoped<IBusPublisher, BusPublisher>();

            // EventsConsumer located into current project
            //services.AddMassTransit<IEventsBus>(x =>
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<EventsConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventsBusOptions>>().Value;

                    cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(_options.UserName);
                        h.Password(_options.Password);
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
                    {
                        ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 15;
                        ep.ConcurrentMessageLimit = _options.UseConcurrencyLimit ?? 16;

                        ep.ConfigureConsumer<EventsConsumer>(context);
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });

            // Consumer for Payment is located in outter project
            // Did I properly describe Bus for outter consumer?
            // I need just publish message to queue with _options.QueueName 
            services.AddMassTransit<IPaymentBus>(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PaymentBusOptions>>().Value;

                    cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(_options.UserName);
                        h.Password(_options.Password);
                    });


                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
                    {
                        ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 15;
                        ep.ConcurrentMessageLimit = _options.UseConcurrencyLimit ?? 16;
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
            services.AddGenericRequestClient();

            #endregion
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do not use answer post types to ask new questions - nobody will be looking for your questions in it.